# Shell script array from command line

Tags: arrays, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a shell script that can accept multiple elements on the command line to be treated as a single array. The command line argument format is:

```
exec trial.sh 1 2 {element1 element2} 4
```

I know that the first two arguments are can be accessed with `$1` and `$2`, but how can I access the array surrounded by the brackets, that is the arguments surrounded by the `{}` symbols?

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to use `exec` to run a shell script.  Just run it using `sh`.

Comment: Hi sorry I am using exec instead of sh because I was redirecting the standard output later, so I suppose the code looks more like ...

exec trial1.sh 1 2 {element1 element2} 4 >> $LOGFILE

Comment: you can still redirect the output even if you run it using `sh`, silly.  
[IO-redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: I'm running the shell script through tcl so sh isn't recognized as a valid command

Comment: **Ooooh**, I thought you were running it in shell!  Lol, that explains why the syntax looks so unusual.  I think `lindex` may be what you're looking for.  [lindex](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/lindex.html)

Comment: Oh sorry about that haha. No I'm executing the script in tcl and trying to figure out how to represent the third command line argument so that trial.tcl treats everything surrounded by {} as an array

Comment: I'm confused... in `tcl` surrounding something in `{}` means that it _is_ an array--tcl calls arrays _lists_, I believe.

Comment: I'm getting a bit closer to figuring it out.. if i run

`exec bash trial.sh 1 2 [list $3] 4` 

then `[list $3]` is treated as a single element. The only issue now is that when I try access the indices of the array, it is treating each character as an index. So I guess it isn't passed as an array its passed as a string? I just need a way change the string into an array, by splitting it wherever there is white space.

Answer (score 0):

This tcl script uses regex parsing to extract pieces of the commandline, transforming your third argument into a list.

Splitting is done on whitespaces - depending on where you want to use this may or may not be sufficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
#
# Sample arguments: 1 2 {element1 element2} 4

# Split the commandline arguments:
# - tcl will represent the curly brackets as \{ which makes the regex a bit ugly as we have to escape this
# - we use '->' to catch the full regex match as we are not interested in the value and it looks good
# - we are splitting on white spaces here
# - the content between the curly braces is extracted
regexp {(.*?)\s(.*?)\s\\\{(.*?)\\\}\s(.*?)$} $::argv -> first second third fourth

puts "Argument extraction:"
puts "argv: $::argv"
puts "arg1: $first"
puts "arg2: $second"
puts "arg3: $third"
puts "arg4: $fourth"

# Third argument is to be treated as an array, again split on white space
set theArguments [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $third]
puts "\nArguments for parameter 3"
foreach arg $theArguments {
    puts "arg: $arg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always place variable length arguments at the end.  But if you can guarantee you always mjust provide the last argument, then something like this will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg1=$1 ; shift
arg2=$1 ; shift

# Get the array passed in.
arrArgs=()
while (( $# > 1 )) ; do
    arrArgs=( "${arrArgs[@]}" "$1" )
    shift
done

lastArg=$1 ; shift
```